# Difference between shared mutex and mutex (why do both exist in C++ 17)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

Haven't got an example online to demonstrate this vividly. Saw an example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/shared_mutex but 
it is still unclear. Can somebody help?

Comment: You should be looking at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) not the header synopsis (as your link shows). BTW, that's C++17 not C++11. The closest was in C++14, which is `std::shared_timed_mutex`. Nonetheless, have you heard of [Readers-Writer Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

By use of normal mutexes, you can guarantee exclusive access to some kind of critical resource – and nothing else. Shared mutexes extend this feature by allowing two levels of access: shared and exclusive as follows:

- Exclusive access prevents any other thread from acquiring the mutex, just as with the normal mutex. It does not matter if the other thread tries to acquire shared or exclusive access.
- Shared access allows multiple threads to acquire the mutex, but *all* of them only in shared mode. Exclusive access is not granted until all of the previous shared holders have returned the mutex (typically, as long as an exclusive request is waiting, new shared ones are queued to be granted *after* the exclusive access).

A typical scenario is a database: It does not matter if several threads read one and the same data simultaneously. But modification of the database is critical - if some thread reads data while another one is writing it might receive inconsistent data. So all reads must have finished before writing is allowed and new reading must wait until writing has finished. After writing, further reads can occur simultaneously again.

*Edit:* Sidenote:

> Why readers need a lock?

This is to prevent the writer from acquiring the lock while reading yet occurs. Additionally, it prevents new readers from acquiring the lock if it is yet held exclusively.

Comment: Very clearly understood we don't want the readers to read stale data while modification is happening and vice versa where read is happening currently so we don't want writer to start making the change to keep data consistent

Answer (score 5):

A shared mutex has two levels of access 'shared' and 'exclusive'.
Multiple threads can acquire shared access but only one can hold 'exclusive' access (that includes there being no shared access).

The common scenario is a read/write lock. Recall that a Data Race can only occur when two threads access the same data **at least one of which is a write**.

The advantage of that is data may be read by many readers but when a writer needs access they must obtain exclusive access to the data.

Why have both? One the one hand the exclusive lock constitutes a normal mutex so arguably only Shared is needed. But there may be overheads in an shared lock implementation that can be avoided using the less featured type.

Here's an example (adapted slightly from the example here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>  
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <thread>
  
std::mutex cout_mutex;//Not really part of the example...
void log(const std::string& msg){
    std::lock_guard guard(cout_mutex);
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}
 
class ThreadSafeCounter {
 public:
  ThreadSafeCounter() = default;
 
  // Multiple threads/readers can read the counter's value at the same time.
  unsigned int get() const {
    std::shared_lock lock(mutex_);//NB: std::shared_lock will shared_lock() the mutex.
    log("get()-begin");
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    auto result=value_;
    log("get()-end");
    return result;
  }
 
  // Only one thread/writer can increment/write the counter's value.
  void increment() {
    std::unique_lock lock(mutex_);
    value_++;
  }
 
  // Only one thread/writer can reset/write the counter's value.
  void reset() {
    std::unique_lock lock(mutex_);
    value_ = 0;
  }
 
 private:
  mutable std::shared_mutex mutex_;
  unsigned int value_ = 0;
};
 
int main() {
  ThreadSafeCounter counter;
 
  auto increment_and_print = [&counter]() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      counter.increment();
      auto ctr=counter.get();
      {
          std::lock_guard guard(cout_mutex);
          std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ' ' << ctr << '\n';
      }
    }
  };
 
  std::thread thread1(increment_and_print);
  std::thread thread2(increment_and_print);
  std::thread thread3(increment_and_print);
 
  thread1.join();
  thread2.join();
  thread3.join();
}
```

Possible partial output:

```
get()-begin
get()-begin
get()-end
140361363867392 2
get()-end
140361372260096 2
get()-begin
get()-end
140361355474688 3
//Etc...
```

Notice how the two `get()-begin()` return show that two threads are holding the shared lock during the read.

Answer (score 4):

"Shared mutexes are usually used in situations when multiple readers can access the same resource at the same time without causing data races, but only one writer can do so."

cppreference.com

This is useful when you need read/writer lock: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock

Comment: Yes i have but threads can simultaneously read data right ? why readers need a lock ? only the modification needs a lock so that the underlying data structure is not broken ?

Comment: @AnandKulkarni Readers needs lock, otherwise they might read the data while another thread is writing to the same data. This is to prevent data race. With a read/writer lock, several readers can access the data simultaneously.