# What does shared mode mean in shared access?

Tags: c++, mutex

In multithreading, there is something called `shared_mutex`. When there is a `shared_mutex`, there are two types of access. A shared access and a exclusive access. I know already what a exclusive access is but what is a shared access? According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46050121/15976718, "*Shared access allows multiple threads to acquire the mutex, but all of them only in shared mode.*" What does he mean by shared mode? What does shared mode do? In shared mode, can you do the same things as exclusive access?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex

Comment: The answer you refer to even gives an example, read-only vs. read-write access. I don't understand what part of that is unclear to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of them as reader and writer locks.

Suppose you have an integer you are guarding with a shared mutex.

You can safely have two threads reading it, so long as no thread is writing it.  But if any thread is writing it, nobody else should be reading it, and nobody else should be writing it, or you risk race conditions.

So the rule is

1. Any number of threads can hold the mutex in shared mode.
2. If any thread holds the mutex in exclusive mode, no other thread can hold the mutex in any mode at all.

There are details, but that should give you the intuition to understand how to use it, and to hang the details off of.

When using a C++ `std` container, you can guard it with a shared mutex, and use shared locks for `const` operations and exclusive for non-`const` operations and avoid C++ memory model contention based race conditions.  (It still doesn't compose, but it isn't bad).  As an example.

```
template<class T>
struct shared_mutex_guarded {
  template<class F>
  auto read(F&& f)const {
    auto l = lock();
    return f(t);
  }
  template<class F>
  auto write(F&& f) {
    auto l = lock();
    return f(t);
  }
  shared_mutex_guarded(T tin):
    t(std::forward<T>(tin))
  {}
private:
  mutable std::shared_mutex m;
  T t;
  auto lock() const {
    return std::shared_lock(m);
  }
  auto lock() {
    return std::unique_lock(m);
  }
};
```

Test code:

```
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

shared_mutex_guarded vec = std::vector<int>{1,2,3};
std::jthread a0([&]{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    while(duration_cast<seconds>(steady_clock::now()-start).count() < 3) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( 100ms );
        std::stringstream ss;
        vec.read([&](auto& vec){
            std::cerr << "Working...\n";
            for (auto i:vec){
                std::this_thread::sleep_for( 10ms );
                ss << i << ",";
            }
            ss << "\n";
            std::cerr << "Solved!\n";
        });
        std::cerr << ss.str();
    }
});
std::jthread a1([&]{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    while(duration_cast<seconds>(steady_clock::now()-start).count() < 3) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( 100ms );
        std::stringstream ss;
        vec.read([&](auto& vec){
            std::cerr << "Summing...\n";
            int sum = 0;
            for (auto i:vec)
            {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for( 10ms );
                sum += i;
            }
            ss << "Sum is " << sum << "\n";
            std::cerr << "Summed!\n";
        });
        std::cerr << ss.str();
    }
});
std::jthread b([&]{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    while(duration_cast<seconds>(steady_clock::now()-start).count() < 3) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( 100ms );
        vec.write([&](auto& vec){
            vec.push_back(vec.back()+1);
            for (auto& i:vec)
                i *= 2;
        });
    }
});
```